# I want to sort values from database

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

my database table's record is look like this:

[image]

I create some php code to join in this table:

```
      $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
      array('sf' => 'sales_order_tax'),
      'sf.order_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sf.amount'));
```

Than I display the amount values:

```
    $this->addColumn('amount', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Amount'),
           'index' => 'amount',
           'filter_index' => 'sf.amount',
           'width' => '50px',
    ));
```

But is not okay, I just want to have one column per each tax in part. For example I need to sort somehow to display only HST-ON code and with their amount. For example: 
HST-ON - 26.63

Thank you

**EDIT:**

This is what I have with my wrong code:

[image]

And here is my entire php file http://collabedit.com/pyqmr

Comment: Do you want to sort or filter?

Comment: I think yes filter is the correct option, thanks

Comment: Please, show us more of your code and explain (1) what you are trying to achieve and (2) what your expected result is. Do you want one row of values, just one value or all rows/values matching a specific criteria?

Comment: So I need to display in column HST-ON for example only amount that have code HST-ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter to the collection to only include rows where the code is HST-ON.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('code', array('eq' => 'HST-ON'));
$collection->getSelect()->...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you made a complete example code for the entire HTS-ON column please?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not quite sure what you want. Do you want a sum of all amounts in rows with the code grouped by its value (one sum for HST-ON , one for GST, etc.)?

Comment: I need to know more, please update your question with more of your code. What is $collection, is is a Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()? Please, post more of your code than just a few snippets, and give an example of what you want to receive.

Comment: can you tell me please if you have all information or you still need anything else?